# joint probability x +y < 4

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is rather simple but I cannot seem to figure out the proper integral ranges.  Take x ~ uniform (0,2) and y ~ uniform (1,3) what is the joint probability that $x + y < 4$?

I've computed it based on the area under the line $y < 4 - x$ to be $\frac{7}{8}$, but I can't figure out the proper double integral ranges for $
\frac{1}{4}\int \int dydx$?

Comment: Why do you need an integral? You have a square with a corner chopped off. The ratio of areas is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a square representing the total allowed area. The top right corner is chopped off (by a line joining the midpoints of two adjacent sides). The area removed is 1/8 of the total. So $p(x+y>4)=1/8$. Hence $p(x+y<4)=7/8$. I can see no good reason to use double integrals.

But if you must, then for the area $x+y<4$ you take $$\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=1}^3\ dy\ dx+\int_{x=1}^2\int_{y=1}^{4-x}\ dy\ dx$$ $$=2+\int_{x=1}^2(3-x)\ dx=2+\frac{3}{2}=\frac{7}{2}$$

The double integral for the full area is $$\int_{x=0}^2\int_{y=1}^3\ dy\ dx=4$$ So $p(x+y<4)=7/8$.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot, I came to the same conclusion graphically but I wanted to be robust from an integral perspective as I couldn't seem to figure out the ranges for the integrals.  To your point on the line doesn't it intersect the square at (1,3) and (2,2) namely the line y=4-x, whose area is then 1/2 less the total area 4 = 3.5?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it slices off the top right corner. So an area 1/2 is excluded from the total area of 4 to give an area of 3.5.